# Why a sequence of functions cannot be dominated by an integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I have $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{n} & |x|\leq n, \\
      0 & |x|>n .
   \end{cases}$$

Why cannot be dominated by an integrable function $g$ by the Dominated Convergence Theorem? I am also wondering what exactly it means for a function $g$ to dominate a sequence of functions, since I believe my definition of this is what I am understanding incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

Well, say $g(x)\geq |f_n(x)|$ for every $x$ and $n$. Then,
$$
g(x)\geq \sup_n|f_n(x)|=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{n} & |x|\in (n-1,n] \\ 0 & x=0 \end{cases}
$$
and thus,
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)\textrm{d}x=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}=\infty
$$
and hence, $g$ cannot be integrable.

Answer (score 2):

$f_n\to 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$, so if the $f_n$ were dominated by an integrable function, DCT would give $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$$ whereas it's obvious that the limit is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

In order to dominate a sequence of functions, it has to be larger than ALL of the functions in the entire sequence.  There is no such $g$ for your sequence of functions, because no matter how large you set $g$ near $0$, it will eventually be exceeded by all the terms in the sequence beyond some point.